# Test to see if first letter is capitalized

Tags: vba, ms-word

I was wondering if there is a way to test if the first letter in a table cell is capitalized without ripping the letter and comparing it to an array full of CHR codes or looping 26 instr() functions for every cell.

Basically, we have clients that send us tables in which the stub cell (far left) has part of the sentences on one line and then the rest on the line below, indented.

The issue is that I can't use the indents to test for these scenarios because other cells are indented for other reasons. I need to apply row shading depending on these scenarios and I'm having a hard time finding an efficient way to test for this.

This code returns 1

```
MsgBox (StrComp("This sentence continues", UCase("This sentence continues"), vbBinaryCompare))
```

This code returns 1 too

```
MsgBox (StrComp("this sentence continues", UCase("This sentence continues"), vbBinaryCompare))
```

Comment: In my answer I stated my assumption that you already have the first character stored. If not, you'll need to extract it from the text using `Left(string,1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you already have the character stored in a string `strFirst`:

```
StrComp(strFirst, UCase(strFirst), vbBinaryCompare)
```

would return 0 if the letter is uppercase.

If you do not already have the first character from the text then you'll need to extract it using `Left(string, 1)`.

Comment: I'm having issues with the vbTextbinary. Unlike most of the built in stuff it doesn't auto adjust the caps ( I type vbtextbinary and it should change to vbTextBinary automatically ) and the function is returning 1 for a string that should return true as well as 1 for a string that should return false.

The strings I'm comparing with strcomp() are
"This string continues"
"on this line"
and both strings return 1 (I'm betting it's because without 
vbtextbinary, the comparison is not case sensitive)

Comment: I have corrected it, it's `vbBinaryCompare`, but did auto-complete not suggest this when you typed your code?

Comment: No, it did not auto update it. vbBinaryCompare looks like it updated correctly but it's still returning 1 for both lines of code (in my post above)

Comment: You know what, I must have stopped reading the code or you updated it again when i wasn't looking but I was comparing an entire string, let me do it with just 1 character...

Comment: Still seems wierd to me that it would work for 1 character and not an entire string since it is a function called labeled strcomp

Comment: It would work if you compared the whole string to `UCase(Left(str,1))&"he rest of the string"`.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the UCase function then. I had it in my head that it was only applying UCase to the first letter, it makes sense why it wouldn't work if it applied it to the entire string.